# Carry out Bivariate Probit Model with unbalanced dependent variables in R

Tags: r, logistic-regression, binomial-coefficients

I am trying to understand to carryout a Bivariate Probit Model to measure differential levels of of individual victimisation. As such, I am trying to model the outcomes of whether an individual is exposed to crime or not and if this has an effect on an individual being a one off or repeat victim. Following on the approach from "Osborn, D.R., Ellingworth, D., Hope, T. and Trickett, A., 1996. Are repeatedly victimized households different?. Journal of Quantitative Criminology, 12, pp.223-245". See page 233.  Here is the data

```r
pdu <- structure(list(polyvictimization9 = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
    yrsaddr_1 = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L
    ), yrsaddr_2 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L), cartot_1 = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L), polyvictimization10 = c(NA, 0L, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    0L, 0L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, 0L, NA, NA, NA, 0L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0L, 0L, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0L, 0L, 0L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0L, NA, 0L, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0L, 0L, 0L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, 0L, 1L, NA, 0L, 0L, NA, NA, 1L, 0L, NA, 0L, NA, NA, 0L, 
    NA, 1L, NA, 0L, NA, NA, 0L, NA, 1L, 0L, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA), cartot_2 = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
    1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    1L, 1L, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-101L))
```

From the data, the 2 binary dependent variables are `polyvictimization9` and `polyvictimization10`. `polyvictimization9` (n = 101) is categorised as 0 = Non victim and 1 = victims (single victim and repeat victims). `polyvictimization10` (n = 31) is obtain by recoding polyvictimization9 into 0 = single victim 1 = repeat victim and NA represents non victims).

To execute the bivariate probit model, I used the `library(GJRM)`. The first model is

- polyvictimization9 ~ yrsaddr_1 + yrsaddr_2 + cartot_1

The second model is

- polyvictimization10 ~ cartot_1 + cartot_2

The two models have some similar IVs and distinct IVs as well.

Here is the code

```r
    bl_pdu <- gjrm(list(polyvictimization9 ~ yrsaddr_1 + yrsaddr_2 + cartot_1, 
                    polyvictimization10 ~ cartot_1 + cartot_2),
               data = pdu, 
               margins = c("probit", "probit"),
               model = "B")
```

This code throws up the error below

```r
    Error in if (check.taus && any(abs(tau) > 0.99999)) stop("some tau is too close to -1 or 1") : 
     missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
    In addition: Warning message:
    In cor(res1, res2, method = "kendall") : the standard deviation is zero
```

Please, I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Your polyvictimization9 are all 1, is that also in your real data the case?

Comment: @jay.sf no, the real data has 0 an 1, but this is just a sample of the data.

Comment: If you look into the source code, `GJRM:::Reg2Copost` internally calculates a tau. It can be due to the data or for other reasons. Suggesting you contact the [maintainer](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/GJRM/index.html). Keep us posted.